# Activar cors en .net core

Tags: api, asp.net-core, cors, .net-core

Al desarrollar un api en .net core y realizar una petición desde React me arroja el siguiente error:

Solicitud de orígenes cruzados bloqueados: La misma política de origen deshabilita la lectura remota del elemento en ‘https://localhost:5001
/formulario/registrar’. (Razón: La credencial no está soportada si el encabezado CORS ‘Access-Control-Permitir-Origen' está ‘*’).

Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://localhost:5001/formulario/registrar. (Razón: Solicitud CORS no exitosa).

y no me regresa la información que le estoy solicitando, mi configuración el la siguiente :
en Statup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

}

y el controlador es el siguiente:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [Route("formulario/registrar")]
    public ActionResult<formulario> Registrar(string titulo)
    {            
        formulario formulario = new formulario();

        formulario.id =3;
        formulario.nombre ="ejemplo";

        return formulario;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece estar todo bien... Pero siempre es problema del orden middleware.

Asi que prueba el orden de .UseCors colocandolo primero (y no tener dudas)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {            
        app.UseHsts();
    }


    app.UseHttpsRedirection();        

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia.

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)